# how to use a variable that contains a file path in qt StyleSheet

Tags: qt, variables, stylesheet

any way to use a qstring variable that contains a file path in stylesheet like that for example

```
connect(ui->comboBox, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(QString)),
ui->listWidget ,SLOT(setStyleSheet("border-image: url("QString");")));
```

Comment: That is not a valid connect statement!? You need to put that `setStyleSheet` code in a proper slot first, or use a lambda. Then you can construct a valid CSS string and use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have access to Qt 5 and C++11, then you can use a lambda Slot, but since `QComboBox::currentIndexChanged` is overloaded it gets a little complicated to use the QString overload.

Try this, I used the `QString::arg` method to build your CSS string, that is usually more readable then simple string concatenation. It simply replaces `%1` with the first argument.

```
connect(comboBox, QOverload<const QString &>::of(&QComboBox::currentIndexChanged),
    [=](const QString &imagePath) { 
        ui->listWidget->setStyleSheet(QString("border-image: url(\"%1\");").arg(imagePath));
});
```